# Find all integers $k$ such that $\frac{k^4+k^3-5k^2+k}{k^2+k-6}$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Find all integers $k$ such that $\frac{k^4+k^3-5k^2+k}{k^2+k-6}$ is an integer.

I tried factorization and ended up with $\frac{k(k^3+k^2-5k+1)}{(k-2)(k+3)}$. Please give me some hints. Thank you!

Comment: See  k =-3 satisfies the $k^3 +k^2 - 5k + 1$ . So $k+3$ is a factor.

Comment: @ChirantanChowdhury Not really $(-3)^3+(-3)^2-5(-3)+1=-2$

Comment: You want first to do polynomial division so that you are left with a numerator of degree less than $2$. Then, if it is not obvious, you can split what remains into partial fractions (i.e. fractions with scalar numerators and denominators $k-2$ and $k+3$). If $|k|$ is too large, these fractions will be too small to give an integer, and there will be a small number of cases left to consider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:
$$\frac{k^4+k^3-5k^2+k}{k^2+k-6}=\frac{(k^2+1)(k^2+k-6)+6}{k^2+k-6}$$